# Is it possible to send a message to Slack channel to further redirect the message to another Slack channel using some scripts or automation

Tags: slack, slack-api

please refer to the architecture diagram that I created to make you all understand my requirements here.
[image]
I'm a new developer API of Slack and trying to build something shown in this diagram and I'm not sure if that is something supported by Slack or not. If yes then what API or documentation links iI should refer to?

I understand that and was able to trigger Slack messages using Slack API directly to a particular Slack channel however I'm looking for something different here that is whenever I trigger a message using Slack API it should arrive in a master or primary Slack channel where with the help of some scripts or automation Slack should read my query parameters or API header to decide which child Slack channel this message belongs and forward that message to it. I'm not sure if something is there to add scripts/automation at the master or primary Slack channel out of the box support by Slack application that can solve this issue for me.

I would really appreciate any guidance on this, thank you

Comment: Look at the [event triggers](https://api.slack.com/automation/triggers/event). However, I do question your architecture. You may have a valid reason for doing it this way, but if a _single_ application is both posting the original message as well as forwarding the messages, why not do that all in the same action?